# Submit SQL data to CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, sql, csv, submit

Hi I am trying to submit msSQL data to create a csv file using PHP; however, when I click submit the csv file is never created. I am wondering if it has something to do with the way I am reading from my database. But I am new to php and sql programming and I am lost as to what is going wrong. Also I have no errors. My code is below.

```
<p>
<input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</p>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
      $db = get_db_connection('swcrc');
      $db->connect();

      $filename = 'uploads/'.strtotime("now").'.csv';

      $fp = fopen($filename,"w");

      $db->query("SELECT [request_ID], [user_ID], [complete], [comment], [response_date], [animalClass], [animalCommon], [bioSurveyStatus]  FROM dbo.Response");
      $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($db);

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db);
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator = "\n";

        echo $seperator;

        fputs($fp,$seperator);

        mysql_data_seek($db,0);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($db))
        {
        $seperator = "";
        $comma = "";

        foreach($row as $name => $value)
        {
            $seperator .= $comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$value);
            $comma = ",";
        }
        $seperator = "\n";
        fputs($fp,$seperator);
        }


        fclose($fp);
  }

?>
```

Thank you for the help and looking.

[image: These are the errors I am receiving when hitting submit]

Comment: All I can think of is, you're trying to open a file based on the current time using `strtotime("now")` which is basically "now" and it doesn't know which one to open, based on the time. --- Can you try and replace that line with an existing document (Using a TEST file) to the affect of `$filename='uploads/testfile.csv';`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fred, I tried what you said to no avail. Do you think it's possible that my submit button is failing to communicate with my php function?

Comment: You're welcome. Actually that could very well be the case. I didn't notice any `<form>...</form>` tags and it needs to be in there when using a submit button, along with a method. I.e.: `<form action="" method="post">`

Comment: Try this `<form action="" method="post"><input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" /></form>`

Comment: So now that I added the form I am able to communicate with the php function but now I have errors. I'm going to take a screen shot and update the question with my list of errors. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the error message as well?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have the error posted now! Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Try and create a blank file called `testfile.csv` and upload it and try it again. Sometimes, it won't write to it unless the file already exists. And make sure it has write permissions.

Comment: I am still having the same error, due to that first permission error, Im going to try and send it to my desktop.

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I moved that file to my desktop, but i am still getting a permission's error first.

Comment: Your PC is your webserver then? Is this Windows/MAC/Linux/other?

Comment: The PC isnt the webserver, I was just seeing if it'd allow me to put it to my desktop since it has permissions to the server. It's a Window's server.

Comment: Ok. Well, Windows webservers are out of my league. I know next to nothing about them. I'm a Unix guy myself; always been.